# JavaScript client for SpringWebFlux to POST data

Tags: server-sent-events, spring-webflux, eventsource

I am playing around with Spring WebFlux to get a taste for reactive API's , however I am struggling to find a solution to "POST" data to a WebFlux endpoint from the JavaScript EventSource API .

My endpoint looks like this :

```
@PostMapping(value="/start/{id}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE , consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Integer> startProcessing(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody ProcessDetails process)
```

And I am easily able to hit the endpoint using POSTMAN , but the JavaScript EventSource api used to get an eventSource is not allowing to send a POST body . The request sent is always a GET request.

```
<script>    
var source = new EventSource("/start/34");
...
```

How can I POST content to a WebFlux endpoint from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

`EventSource` and in general, Server Sent Events are unidirectional, from server to client ([see reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource)).

If you'd like to POST data from a browser to the server, any regular AJAX POST will work.

Note that with your current endpoint setup, the browser should send a POST request with a JSON body and then receive an infinite stream of SSEs.

If you'd like to have a bidirectional stream of messages, then WebSockets is the answer here. Spring WebFlux currently supports raw WebSockets, so no Sock.js/STOMP abstraction is available for now.

Comment: Is there a way to send a XHR from the browser to receive a stream of data from the server without using EventSource API ? I would love to see an sample impl.

The problem POSTING a request first and grabbing an event source generated with a second call - is that it introduces the requirement of having a STATE in the server , session propagation between multiple nodes OR having sticky sessions enabled becomes a requirement. Services should be stateless.

Comment: I’m not aware of a way to do that. I don’t think you can post data with event source. Maybe websockets and stomp are the way to go here.

Comment: After posting a XMLHttpRequest to your WebFlux service, you can listen onreadystatechange to stream the result.